# Trying to make a filter with grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to make a filter that capture all the `.exe` file lines. For example, from this:

```
[05/Apr/2010:11:00:01 -0300] /~mauro/Lista_conceitos_BD_2004.DOC 200 46080

[05/Apr/2010:11:00:54 -0300] /~lucia/articles/PROPOR96-Rino.pdf 200 153253

[05/Apr/2010:11:01:32 -0300] /~daniel_leite/RenomearTudo/setup.exe 200 1692017

[05/Apr/2010:11:02:12 -0300] /~grv/tutrv/fig23.jpg 200 22821

[05/Apr/2010:11:04:11 -0300] /~lucia/TechRep/NILCTR981-RMartinse
```

I want to get this:

```
[05/Apr/2010:11:01:32 -0300] /~daniel_leite/RenomearTudo/setup.exe 200 1692017
```

I'm trying with `grep -w '*.exe' filteredAccessLog > filteredSuccessIMGAccessLog` but it is not working at all. If someone could help, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asterisk means *, and the . means "any character".  Give this a try:

```
grep "\.exe" filteredAccessLog > filteredSuccessIMGAccessLog
```

Answer (score 5):

`grep -F .exe filteredAccessLog > filteredSuccessIMGAccessLog`

Comment: I'd use -F (fixed strings) with that, otherwise . matches any character.

Answer (score 2):

That asterisk may not mean what you may think it means. In regular expressions, asterisk means 0 or more repetitions of the previous character or group.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave out the asterisk:

```
grep -w '.exe' filteredAccessLog > filteredSuccessIMGAccessLog
```